# SQL Server 2008 Insert with WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have existing records like

```
ID    Hospital ID     Email                Description 
1       15         abc@e.com           Sample Description
2       15         def@dd.com          Random Text
```

I need to use a WHILE loop to insert rows with Hospital ID changing to a specific value or 32 in this case, while the others(not ID as it is auto generated) remaining constant.

It should then look like

```
ID    Hospital ID     Email                Description 
1       15         abc@e.com           Sample Description
2       15         def@dd.com          Random Text
3       32         abc@e.com           Sample Description
4       32         def@dd.com          Random Text
```

Notice the above now has two new rows with ID and Hospital ID different. ID is auto generated.

I have several tables where I need to make the same updates. I don't want to use cursor if I can do this with a while loop.

**EDIT**
Abandoned while loop as a simpler solution was provided in the accepted answer.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Of course. I don't know how to write the insert query. I tried declaring @hospitalid int and the looping with while loop with @@RowCount.

Comment: Put in some code here.

Comment: where is the value of `HospitalID` came from?

Comment: I am setting the new HospitalID myself. Hardcoded.

Comment: @navi - If I knew how to write I wouldn't ask the question. Try to be constructive.

Comment: I was only asking your research on the same.

Comment: More like, what you had tried.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that `ID` is an identity column:

```
INSERT INTO TheTable(HospitalID, Email, Description)
SELECT 32, Email, Description FROM TheTable
WHERE HospitalID <> 32
```

Try to avoid loops with SQL. Try to think in terms of sets instead.

Comment: That just works. Thank you. Just curious to learn though, can you think of a way to do with WHILE LOOP? would that mean creating a temp table to store temp values?

Comment: I would never use a `WHILE` loop. Whenever I find my self using code like that, I stop what I'm doing and start over.

Answer (score 21):

First of all I'd like to say that I 100% agree with John Saunders that you must avoid loops in SQL in most cases especially in production.

But occasionally as a one time thing to populate a table with a hundred records for testing purposes IMHO it's just OK to indulge yourself to use a loop.

For example in your case to populate your table with records with hospital ids between 16 and 100 and make emails and descriptions distinct you could've used

```
CREATE PROCEDURE populateHospitals
AS
DECLARE @hid INT;
SET @hid=16;
WHILE @hid < 100
BEGIN 
    INSERT hospitals ([Hospital ID], Email, Description) 
    VALUES(@hid, 'user' + LTRIM(STR(@hid)) + '@mail.com', 'Sample Description' + LTRIM(STR(@hid))); 
    SET @hid = @hid + 1;
END
```

And result would be

```
ID   Hospital ID Email            Description          
---- ----------- ---------------- ---------------------
1    16          user16@mail.com  Sample Description16 
2    17          user17@mail.com  Sample Description17 
...                                                    
84   99          user99@mail.com  Sample Description99
```

Comment: The accepted answer slightly modified does what I am looking for. I was not trying to increase the HospitalID. My question shows the example of what I was looking to get.

Comment: @TejaswiRana The question shows example but not intent behind it. You can use const value for HospitalID `32` in my example if you want to. But if you want to just duplicate existing set of records exactly as they are while changing value of one column then @JohnSaunders' solution is the best way to go.