# SQL Server INSERT new records

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2012

Before I posted this I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182468/sql-server-2008-insert-with-while-loop) too. But I thought may be my issue was slightly different.

I have a scenario  where my table struct is as follows:

**my_table**:

```
my_id | what_I_have | what_I_can_do
```

I don't have a primary key because the table is a lookup table (nothing fundamental). All I want is to get a set of values for `my_id`, which is based on certain values for `what_I_have`, and `what_I_can_do`. Once I get a resultset (with `my_d`), I want to insert new records into `my_table` for each of the `my_id` in the result set with additional information for other columns.

E.g.

```
01001 | boxes | delivery  | (existing)
01002 | boxes | delivery  | (existing)
01001 | boxes | unpacking | (new)
01002 | boxes | unpacking | (new)
```

I have thought about doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(my_id, what_I_have, what_I_can_do, my_customer_company)
    SELECT 
        my_id, 'boxes', 'unpacking' 
    FROM 
        my_table (NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        my_id IN (SELECT b.my_id FROM my_table b(NOLOCK) 
                  WHERE b.what_I_have = 'boxes' 
                    AND b.what_I_can_do = 'delivery')
```

I know that there might be a way to use `INNER JOIN` and get this done smoothly without "nesting". But is this going to work or am I missing something here?

KR,

Comment: "I don't have a primary key because the table is a lookup table" - that logic is flawed.

Comment: Not sure why the join is required?

Comment: just put your sub query where clause in the other query where clause

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: ***Every*** table ought to have a **primary key** - how else are you going to identify each individual row?

Comment: @MitchWheat     what I meant was that the my_id is a PK for a different table 'my_items'. I perform association of data on 'my_table' based on PKs from other table, so they are technically all Foreign keys with no PKs for 'my_table'. It's not about flaw.....thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @marc_s        no every table doesn't have to have a PK...it's very uncommon __not__ to have one, but it's not impossible....it all depends on your purpose.....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need nesting or a `join` at all:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(my_id, what_I_have, what_I_can_do, my_customer_company)
    SELECT my_id, 'boxes', 'unpacking'
    FROM my_table
    WHERE what_I_have = 'boxes' AND what_I_can_do = 'delivery';
```